# Materialized View Performance of Exists vs In

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, materialized-views

I did some googling and couldn't find a clear answer to an oracle performance question.  Maybe we can document it here. I am building an MV that is pretty simple but on fairly large tables. The query like many things can be written more than one way. In my case when written as a select statement two solutions have similar costs / execution plan, but when placed inside of a create materialized view the execution time changes drastically. Any insight into why?

- Tab1 is aprox 40M records.
- Tab2 is aprox 8M records.
- field1 is a primary key on Tab1, it is not a PK or unique on Tab2 but tab 2 does have an index on this field.
- field2 is not a key nor is it indexed on either table (boo)

Queries are:

## Q1:

```
SELECT
    CR1.Several_Fields
FROM 
    SCHEMA1.tab1 T1
WHERE T1.field2 like 'EXAMPLE%'
AND T1.field1 not in (
    SELECT T2.field1
    FROM SCHEMA1.tab2 T2
)
;
```

## Q2:

```
SELECT
    CR1.Several_Fields
FROM 
    SCHEMA1.tab1 T1
WHERE T1.field2 like 'EXAMPLE%'
AND  not exists (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SCHEMA1.tab2 T2
    WHERE T1.field1 = T2.field1
)
;
```

The two queries as select statements run similarly in time, and explain plan has them both utilizing the index scan rather than full table scans as I would expect. What is unexpected is that Q2 runs vastly faster (47 seconds vs 81 days per v$session_longops) when run in an mv creation like:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SCHEMA1.mv_blah as
(
  Q1 or Q2
);
```

Does anyone have any insight, is there a rule here to not use IN if possible for mviews only? I know of the tricks between in and exist when indexes do not exist between the tables but this one had me baffled. This is running against an oracle 11g database.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan of materialized view creation for both Q1 and Q2?

Comment: In 11g with SQL developer you cannot get oracle to show the exec plan once you wrap in the MV, just as a select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a known bug. If you have access to My Oracle Support look at [Slow Create/Refresh of Materialized View Based on NOT IN Definition Query (Doc ID 1591851.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1591851.1), or less usefully if you don't, [a summary of the problem is available](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1591851_1.html).

The contents of the MOS version can't be reproduced here of course, but suffice to say that the only workaround is what you're already doing with `not exists`. It's fixed in 12c, which doesn't help you much.

Comment: This is excellent. Obviously for now we just need to write as a not exists but knowing that there is a pending fix and we can basically let folks know for oracle 11g and lower this is a thing should help.

I wonder why the first article did not come up in my searching but either way i appreciate you knowing and finding it. I will just have to complain to the DBAs to upgrade the entire database to fix my one query now :)

Comment: One other thing to be aware of is that the query used in the MV definition is only used explicitly as written during the MV creation. Oracle may automatically rewrite it, adding hints or changing other things around, during a refresh and there's no ability to control that.

Comment: @pmdba - surely that's true during the create as well (since the bug is both create and refresh); and indeed for all other queries to some extent?